# How to do dynamic entry data validation in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, verification

[Example of one Table][2]

I have a structure of an Excel Project with 5 tables that are being updated regularly. I am currently working on finding a way to validate entered data and set a frame and a specific datatype for certain columns. If there is a wrong entry it should return a message. I have tried using vba, but since I am not experienced at all I struggled to implement a working code. The data check option from excel did not work so far either since there should also be the option to copy and paste several datasets in the table at once. It also keeps resetting as soon as i close the project.

Is it a good idea to keep trying it with vba?

My idea is to run through each column in a loop and check each entry for certain requirements assigned to the column. There should be a message box throwing an error in case that the entered data has the wrong datatype or is out of the chosen range.

```
Sub CheckColumns()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long

lCol = Range("C2").End(xlToRight).Column
lRow = Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

For Each rng In Range("C2", Cells(lRow, lCol))
    If IsNumeric(rng) = False Then
         MsgBox ("A number has to be entered " & "Row " & rng.Row & 
" Column " & rng.Column)
         rng.Font.ColorIndex = 3
         
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you grant any data sample and expected result and maybe what have you tried so far? Your description is really too vague and broad to be addressed with a specific answer.

Comment: Data validation is ca good place to start.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Yes of course. So I added a picture of a sample table. What I want is to read in all the information that I entered in the table and to check for certain requirements. In this case this would be that the name can only contain letters and that the length width and height have to be floats and are in a certain range

Comment: @RaduPacurar My problem with the data validation tool ist that if I use drag and drop the excel validation tool does not work anymore

Comment: Please do NOT include links to images of code etc. Place the image in the question itself or copy/past code.

Comment: @slipoch unfortunately I am not allowed to include images in my post yet.

Comment: Then include it as a table in the text. Everything needed to ask a question should be on the ticket itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngNameColumn As Range
    Dim RngLenghtColumn As Range
    Dim RngWidthColumn As Range
    Dim RngHeightColumn As Range
    Dim RngIntersection As Range
    Dim RngCell As Range
    Dim StrMessage As String
    Dim StrMessageReason As String
    Dim BytCounter As Byte
    Dim DblLenghtMax As Double
    Dim DblWidthMax As Double
    Dim DblHeightMax As Double
    Dim DblLenghtMin As Double
    Dim DblWidthMin As Double
    Dim DblHeightMin As Double
    
    'Settings.
    Set RngNameColumn = Me.Range("B:B")
    Set RngLenghtColumn = Me.Range("C:C")
    Set RngWidthColumn = Me.Range("D:D")
    Set RngHeightColumn = Me.Range("E:E")
    DblLenghtMax = 5000
    DblWidthMax = 243
    DblHeightMax = 4354
    DblLenghtMin = 2354
    DblWidthMin = 24
    DblHeightMin = 333
    
    'Setting the first part of StrMessage.
    StrMessage = "Invalid input:"
    
    
    '___________________________
    'RngNameColumn Block - Start
    '---------------------------
    'In this block RngNameColumn is checked for invalid input.
    
    'Setting RngIntersection.
    Set RngIntersection = Intersect(Target, RngNameColumn)
    
    'Setting the StrMessageReason accordingly to the block need.
    StrMessageReason = ": no digits allowed"
    
    'Checking if RngIntersection is something.
    If Not RngIntersection Is Nothing Then
        
        'Covering each cell of RngIntersection.
        For Each RngCell In RngIntersection
            
            'Covering each digit.
            For BytCounter = 0 To 9
                
                'Checking if RngCell contains any digit.
                If Len(RngCell.Value) <> Len(Excel.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(RngCell.Value, BytCounter, "")) And _
                   RngCell.Value <> "" Then
                    
                    'Setting StrMessage.
                    StrMessage = StrMessage & vbCrLf & "-range " & RngIntersection.EntireColumn.Address(0, 0) & StrMessageReason
                    
                    'When the first invalid input of the block is found, the block is left.
                    GoTo CP_RngNameColumnEnd
                    
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
CP_RngNameColumnEnd:
    
    '___________________________
    'RngNameColumn Block - End
    '---------------------------
    
    
    '_____________________________
    'RngLenghtColumn Block - Start
    '-----------------------------
    'In this block RngLenghtColumn is checked for invalid input.
    
    'Setting RngIntersection.
    Set RngIntersection = Intersect(Target, RngLenghtColumn)
    
    'Setting the StrMessageReason accordingly to the block need.
    StrMessageReason = ": has be be a number between " & DblLenghtMax & " and " & DblLenghtMin
    
    'Checking if RngIntersection is something.
    If Not RngIntersection Is Nothing Then
        
        'Covering each cell of RngIntersection.
        For Each RngCell In RngIntersection
            
            'Checking if RngCell does not contain a number within the specified limits.
            If (IsNumeric(RngCell.Value) = False Or _
                RngCell.Value < DblLenghtMin Or _
                RngCell.Value > DblLenghtMax _
               ) And _
               RngCell.Value <> "" Then
               
                'Setting StrMessage.
                StrMessage = StrMessage & vbCrLf & "-range " & RngIntersection.EntireColumn.Address(0, 0) & StrMessageReason
                
                'When the first invalid input of the block is found, the block is left.
                GoTo CP_RngLenghtColumnEnd
                
            End If
        Next
    End If
CP_RngLenghtColumnEnd:
    
    '_____________________________
    'RngLenghtColumn Block - End
    '-----------------------------
    
    
    '_____________________________
    'RngWidthColumn Block - Start
    '-----------------------------
    'In this block RngWidthColumn is checked for invalid input.
    
    'Setting RngIntersection.
    Set RngIntersection = Intersect(Target, RngWidthColumn)
    
    'Setting the StrMessageReason accordingly to the block need.
    StrMessageReason = ": has be be a number between " & DblWidthMax & " and " & DblWidthMin
    
    'Checking if RngIntersection is something.
    If Not RngIntersection Is Nothing Then
        
        'Covering each cell of RngIntersection.
        For Each RngCell In RngIntersection
            
            'Checking if RngCell does not contain a number within the specified limits.
            If (IsNumeric(RngCell.Value) = False Or _
                RngCell.Value < DblWidthMin Or _
                RngCell.Value > DblWidthMax _
               ) And _
               RngCell.Value <> "" Then
               
                'Setting StrMessage.
                StrMessage = StrMessage & vbCrLf & "-range " & RngIntersection.EntireColumn.Address(0, 0) & StrMessageReason
                
                'When the first invalid input of the block is found, the block is left.
                GoTo CP_RngWidthColumnEnd
                
            End If
        Next
    End If
CP_RngWidthColumnEnd:
    
    '_____________________________
    'RngWidthColumn Block - End
    '-----------------------------
    
    
    '_____________________________
    'RngHeightColumn Block - Start
    '-----------------------------
    'In this block RngHeightColumn is checked for invalid input.
    
    'Setting RngIntersection.
    Set RngIntersection = Intersect(Target, RngHeightColumn)
    
    'Setting the StrMessageReason accordingly to the block need.
    StrMessageReason = ": has be be a number between " & DblHeightMax & " and " & DblHeightMin
    
    'Checking if RngIntersection is something.
    If Not RngIntersection Is Nothing Then
        
        'Covering each cell of RngIntersection.
        For Each RngCell In RngIntersection
            
            'Checking if RngCell does not contain a number within the specified limits.
            If (IsNumeric(RngCell.Value) = False Or _
                RngCell.Value < DblHeightMin Or _
                RngCell.Value > DblHeightMax _
               ) And _
               RngCell.Value <> "" Then
               
                'Setting StrMessage.
                StrMessage = StrMessage & vbCrLf & "-range " & RngIntersection.EntireColumn.Address(0, 0) & StrMessageReason
                
                'When the first invalid input of the block is found, the block is left.
                GoTo CP_RngHeightColumnEnd
                
            End If
        Next
    End If
CP_RngHeightColumnEnd:
    
    '_____________________________
    'RngHeightColumn Block - End
    '-----------------------------
    
    'If StrMessage has changed since its initial value, it is reported.
    If StrMessage <> "Invalid input:" Then
        MsgBox StrMessage, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Invalid input"
    End If
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! @Evil Blue Monkey unfortunately the code does not work. What could the issue of this be? Are there any variables i have to adjust?

Comment: Hard to say for me. "The code does not work" is too vague for any real guess on the nature of the problem. Can you be more specific? The part of the code that you need to check and properly set is the settings (at the beginning of the code right after the declarations). The first 4 variables identify the columns where the data are stored. The following 6 variables are the min and max values for each numeric data. Play with those data and see what happens.

Comment: Okay so what I did is that I copied the code into my worksheet, when I put invalid data into my table there is nothing happening. I checked everything but I don't see where there might be a problem. I tried adjusting the values but unfortunately it didn't work out. I copied another version of the code in the description. Here I am still missing the validation of whether the data is in range though.

Comment: You've accepted the answer. Is it working now?

Comment: It is working! Thank you! I am just trying to combine it with the other code I wrote :)